# Lexmark cx317dn - unwanted artifacts on page

Tags: printer, laser-printer, lexmark-printer

I have a [Lexmark cx317dn](https://www.lexmark.com/en_gb/printer/11102/Lexmark-CX317dn) and apart from the cost of consumables it is an excellent printer. Lately however I've been seeing these unwanted artifacts on pages. Can anyone help me troubleshoot and fix this as it's quite annoying?

[image: Lexmark cx317dn - unwanted artifacts on page]

Comment: I wonder if it could be related to the government-mandated watermarking?  Is there still a pattern of tiny yellow dots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measure the distance between the dots, and compare it with the measurements shown on the [Lexmark CS/CX310 Print Defects Guide](https://publications.lexmark.com/publications/lexmark_hardware/CS31x/HMP/en/print-defects-page.pdf). That will tell you which roller to replace.

You can use this [Lexmark Support Page](http://support.lexmark.com/index?id=SO7199&page=content&locale=EN&userlocale=EN_UK) for more details.

Comparing the image you attached with the Print Defects Guide, I'm guessing the spacing between your marks is 25.1 mm, which means the culprit is the [photoconductor unit](https://www.lexmark.com/en_ca/supply/7614/Lexmark-CS-CX31x-41x-51x-4-Pack-40K-Photoconductor-Kit). Start by having a look at it, to see if you can spot the roller that has the mark. If something is stuck to the roller, it may be possible to remove to remove it, *very gently!*

However, with only your embedded image as a guide, it's impossible to be certain of the exact distances. You either need to measure it yourself, or attach a full-size scan.

Answer (score 3):

As the spots are regularly spaced, this seem like a problem with the
drum/roller. From the colors, the problem seems to be with the
black and magenta colors. Sometimes this is caused by dirt stuck
on the drum/roller, or even external objects causing damage.

The
[Lexmark CX317dn Manuals](https://www.manualslib.com/products/Lexmark-Cx317dn-8944656.html)
are not very informative, but I gather from them that you have several
units that might be concerned.

Not familiar with Lexmark printers, I can't give exact instructions on
cleaning. You might find some pointers in the article
[How to clean Lexmark printer rollers](https://www.printerfixes.com/how-to-clean-lexmark-printer-rollers/).

If you cannot find the unit that needs cleaning, new parts are available
but seem expensive.
See the Amazon query for
[Lexmark Drum cx310](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Lexmark+Drum+cx310&crid=3FTM033JZ59NE&sprefix=lexmark+drum+cx310%2Caps%2C141&ref=nb_sb_noss).